# Do I need to use a lock object when accessing data in my Xamarin Forms SQLite object?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am always doing this:

```
lock (l)
{
    try
    {
        var data = db2.Query<CardSetWithWordCount>(qry);
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        db2.Rollback();
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.WriteLine(qry);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But is it needed to use the lock object? I keep getting conflicting opinions from work mates.

Comment: In general, no, you do not have to, but it really depends upon if you are accessing the DB from multi-threads and need the latest records (i.e. If you have one thread that is retrieving new data from an remote source and updating the database and another thread is querying that data for display and you want to lock out that query until the update is done, etc...). I have done some intense Sqlite mobile apps and not one has a `lock` statement in it, just depends upon your usage pattern and how you design/architect the app for that pattern....

Comment: BTW: Why try/catch a query and perform a rollback? What are you rolling back? and how does that query fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are only querying your database to retrieve data, like you're doing in your example, there is absolutely no need to lock anything.

Locking your database layer can be usefull if your app does a lot of background manipulation of the database.

In most cases (for mobile apps), you tend to do 1 operation at a time, so locking is not necessary.